# PHP Soap Server: instantiate with a string (xml string) instead of WSDL file (url to it)

Tags: php, string, soap, wsdl

The PHP page of Soap Server (I've seen it):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/soapserver.soapserver.php

But I'm missing an important lack of documentation there for my very own problem:

I need to know if it's possible to instantiate the Server directly with an XML string, like `SimpleXML` class does:

```
//From var (the one I want):
$movies = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr);
```

or

```
//From file and from string (the one I want):
$xml = simplexml_load_file('test.xml');

$xml = simplexml_load_string($string);
```

So I would like to do something like this:

```
$wsdl_cont = file_get_contents("../xmls/mywsdl.wsdl");
$server = new SoapServer($wsdl_cont);
```

Is it possible?

The reason for this is, because I have some different URLs which have to use the same XML, so I need to do a replace on the fly on a template URL, and change it to the right one and then, load the WSDL. But I don't want to save on HDD the instantly generated WSDL to delete it right after having it read.

Is it possible to create some kind of "virtual file" on PHP and use it like if it was a disk read one? Some kind o stream buffer? Or some kind of file descriptor on the fly?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yes it's possible by creating a [DATA URI](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.data.php) out of the files content and use it as "file".

```
$name = 'mywsdl.wsdl';
$path = '/path-to-file/'.$name;
$data = file_get_contents($path);
$file = 'data://text/plain;base64,'.base64_encode($data);
$server = new SoapServer($file);
```

This should do what you're looking for. A [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5946963/handle-xml-catalogs-by-php/5947149#5947149).

Comment: OMG! Now, THAT's an answer! Thank you so much! You made my day :_)

Comment: Note: The data uri approach seems not to work with PHP5.2.. I tested it successfully with PHP5.3.3+ though.

Comment: Note2: Using this approach may consume a big amount of memory, depending on how big your wsdl is.

Comment: @staabm: Yes, this goes into the string and therefore into the memory. As an alternative you can use a local cache of those files. I have written about it on Stackoverflow and as well on my blog which should link some useful resources: [Using Catalogs for Validation with PHP’s DOMDocument and Libxml2](http://hakre.wordpress.com/2012/12/17/using-catalogs-for-validation-with-phps-domdocument-and-libxml2/)

Comment: With this approach, 1 out of 5 calls I get the PHP Warning: SoapServer::SoapServer(): I/O warning : failed to load external entity &quot;data://text/plain;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc... !

Comment: @dgaspar: That's mot likely to other errors, not to the `data://text/plain` encoding itself.

Comment: Why do I have to encode and decode it in base64 back and forth? This seems like a waste of resources.

Comment: @German: Try what suits you, plain does not work IIRC last time I tried with XML, *maybe* url percent-encoding does but IIRC I tried that as well and it didn't turn out working. But just try what suits you, and if it works, don't forget to keep on commenting, then others can certainly benefit from your findings.